# Library of footprints for Cadence Allegro / PCB Editor

Tags: pcb-design, software, footprint, allegro

I keep having to design my own footprints for Cadence Allegro / PCB Editor even for standard parts. There are lots of libraries for schematic capture symbols but I am having trouble finding footprints.

Can somebody point me towards a library of PCB footprints?

Comment: check here http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/AllegroExchange

Comment: Is this for OrCAD? You have that tag but say Allegro. Or is Allegro part of OrCAD?

Comment: @BrianCarlton This is for Allegro. I used the Orcad tag because there is none for Allegro and most Orcad users will also be using Allegro.

Comment: @Arik Raffael Funke, I created allegro tag and added it here.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I did not find much there. The group has a total of merely 31 messages since 2008.

Comment: Mmm I always had basics footprints available for components such as resistors, capacitors, BJT, etc. in our PCB Editor's installation folder. Have you browsed it?

Answer (score 1):

Look on github : https://github.com  there are really a lot cadence allegro pcb foot prints on there.

Separate Search words to use one a time on github are :  Cadence  , ORCAD , allegro

and then you will a lot of foot print.

I suggest that you check the foot prints carefully a lot are chinese made .
From past experience you need to check engineering output from China to 
make sure that it is up to a standard that you your self would be happy 
to use.

Answer (score 0):

SnapEDA (http://www.snapeda.com) just launched Cadence OrCAD an Allegro as export formats this week for PCB footprint and schematic symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I must say, foreign footprints never pay off. You should build your own library, where eaxh symbol is checked by yourself, and later by production. Otherwise you can't trust it.